# how to display scientific notation to power of 10 in java?

Tags: java

Is there any way to i can display large numbers in powers of "10" instead of "E" like this:

```
1x10²
```

instead of:

```
1.0E2
```

Thanks

Comment: Where exactly you want to display it? Console, web page, some document, somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

If performance doesn't matter you could write your own procedure to do the conversion.

```
public String toScientific(String input) {
    String result = "";
    int indexOfE = input.indexOf("E");

    result = input.substring(0, indexOfE); // Get first part (e.g. "1.0")
    result += " x 10^"; // Add "x 10^" --> "1.0 x 10^"
    result += input.substring(indexOfE + 1, input.length()); // Add exponent

    return result;
}
```

Input : *"1.0E2"* , Output : *"1.0 x 10^2"*

Comment: final Function<String, String> fnScientificFrontendDisplay = input ->
            Optional.ofNullable(input)
                    .map(s -> s.split("E"))
                    .filter(tokens -> tokens.length != 2)
                    .map(tokens -> tokens[0] + "x10^" + tokens[1])
                    .orElse(null);

Answer (score 2):

There is in fact a way to print out superscript characters. Unicode allows you to print any digit from 0 to 9 as a superscript (2070 to 2079, see http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf)

From there it is a matter of reading your input number and some string formatting to determine which Unicode characters need to be printed. Unfortunately I don't think there is a prebuilt library in java which does this for you. Let me know if you need sample code and I can provide it.

EDIT: This is good for the console. If you need to put it into a GUI component, `JLabel` can accept HTML so you can say `new JLabel("<html>1x10<sup>2</sup></html>");` to display that in a form.